# How to accept every SSL certificate with firefox?

Tags: firefox

I have Firefox 50.1.0.

I need to know what property to set to accept all untrusted SSL certificate without question?

I found solutions over google but they don't work with the said version.

I need to do the same thing that is done there:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxProfile_AcceptUntrustedCertificates.htm

Comment: You do realize this is an awful idea, right?

Comment: I do, but this is for a specific context. I added a link in my question.